# hibernate and sqlserver concurrency issues?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I have a webservice exposed, which will save some data into a certain table. i am using sqlserver database. multiple systems can consume the webservice at the same time.

The problem is that two systems are checking the existence of the record and reporting false, inserting a new record at the same time, which is leading to concurrency exception due to duplicate key.

I am using hibernate and the systems whichever are calling the webservice supplies the primarykey also.

Here can i make the method as `synchronized`? will there be disadvantages or is there any elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using `synchronised` or even using Java/Hibernate to avoid duplicates; if you had to scale your existing application or added another application that modified the data you would still have this problem.

The best way to do this is to set a unique constraint on the table to avoid duplicates; this allows you to handle the unique constraint violation when you insert the duplicate and do what ever you wish.